# Is it normal to use “do” as an intransitive verb for ‘change”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was interested in the expression, “Change does slow” in the following sentence of [NPR’s article](http://www.npr.org/blogs/health/2013/01/03/168567019/you-cant-see-it-but-youll-be-a-different-person-in-10-years) (January 3) titled “You can see it, but you’ll be a different person in 10 years:

> “But that doesn’t mean they fully understand what’s still to come.
>   “Their estimates of how much they’ll change in the future are underestimates,” says Danie Gilber (psychology researcher at Harvard Univ.). “They are going to change more than they realize. **Change does slow**; **it just doesn’t slow** as much as we think it will.”

Though I understand the meaning, I don’t think I’ve heard “Change does slow (fast)” very often. I thought Change occurs, happens, takes place, progresses, accelerates, goes on, but didn’t think of Change does (slow / fast).

Is the use of ‘does’ in “Change does slow (fast)” a normal way of wording to mean the slowness / rapidness of the process of change?

Comment: It's just another way of saying "Change does slow down" or "Change does get slower" or "Change slows down". It's normal and idiomatic American English. But *"Change does fast" is not normal. That'd have to be "Change does speed up" or "Change speeds up" or "Change gets faster".

Comment: So 'Does’ functions here as an auxiliary verb, not a transitive verb followed by adverb (slow).

Comment: Right. The main verb is "slow" or "slow down". And if "does" were a transitive verb, it would have to be followed by a direct object, which is always a noun phrase and never an adverb.

Comment: Bill's first comment is right.  A sentence earlier in the article indicates that speed of change is being talked about: “Personality changes do take place faster when people are younger, says Gilbert”.

Comment: this type of construction is usually called verum focus.

Comment: @Bill Franke. If ‘does’ is an auxiliary verb, can I dispense with it? Is it awkward to say simply ‘Change slows (down)’? Additionally, can I say 'Change goes slow' by using 'slow' as an adverb ?

Comment: You can say it in a number of different ways, with or without the _do_ auxiliary, yes. The best way of saying it is always a function of context. "Change slows (down)" or "Change goes slow(ly)". The meaning won't change, but the style will. They're all grammatical. The writer/speaker of the NPR program might have just as easily said: "Change slows, but not as much as we think it will." Repeating the subject+verb emphasizes the idea that change slows, as does including the aux "does/doesn't".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sentence *Change does slow*, the verb is "slow" (i.e. become slower).  "Does" is an auxiliary verb used for emphasis.

Read it as *Change definitely is slowing.*

Comment: Or as, "the rate of change is slowing," perhaps?

Comment: "It was my understanding that there would be no math."

Answer (score 7):

It is actually "slow" that is the intransitive verb here. "Do" in this case is just for emphasis. You could say "Change slows", but with *do*, the you are more assertively making the claim about the fact that change slows.

See [Do-support, under "for emphasis"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support)

Comment: Exactly; as an alternative, one could say "Change indeed slows", where Change is the noun subject